# Reset MySQL value every day with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a PHP hit counter that saves the hits in to MySQL. It would be best if I could somehow get a count for every day, but so far I haven't figured how to do that without it being too complicated.
So, for now (unless someone here has a solution for above ^) I want to reset the "todays hits" in MySQL every day, at 00:00.
I could not seem to find a way of scheduling this to be executed automaticly every day at 00:00 (GMT 0, UK time).

Comment: You can acomplish it with a cron job

Comment: So you would rather re-set a counter to zero rather than do the work necessary to have a query get that info for you? Re-setting to zero means you don't have the historical data to go back to right?

Comment: why not having one row of data everyday? then you just add the value to the existing row or insert a new row if none exist for 'today'.

Comment: How would I do this, @Jeff?

Answer (score 3):

You have two solutions:

Use the event scheduler for mysql

```
CREATE EVENT 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2015-01-07 00:00:00'
DO
[SQL for reset the value here];
```

Other solution is use an PHP script and execute it with cron

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
[PHP script for reset the value here]
```

Then, add it to the cron jobs

```
 0 22 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /usr/local/bin/my-daily-script.php &> /dev/null
```

(You can change 22 for other hour value)

Answer (score 1):

Giancarlo answers your question absolutely correct,
but I'd suggest to have a different approach:

have a "hits"-table with the fields

```
hitsDate (date) | hits (int)
----------------------------------
2015-01-06    | 329
2015-01-05    | 0
```

Everytime you want to add a hit (on login maybe? or on session start?) compare with the current date:

```
Update hits_table set hits=hits+1 where hitsDate=curdate()
```

If this returns an error or false, then there is no row to be updated, so we insert a new one with the current date and the first hit:

```
Insert into hits_table (hitsDate, hits) values (curdate(), 1)
```

Now you can view the hits for any day you want, can make nice charts, ...